# Customizing the root element of an Ember.js DS.RESTSerializer

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, odata

I am working with an OData compliant back end which expects a certain json structure.

To change the default POST request data that your ember model is serialized into you can create your own serializer on a per model basis.  I have a question model with a text attribute.

serializer

```
Excelsior.QuestionSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serialize: (question, options) ->
    json = {
        text: "lalalala"
    }
```

output

```
{question: {text: "lalalala"}}
```

what I would like

```
{d: {text: "lalala"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter is what's namespacing the data, so if you override the relevant methods in your adapter, you can change that functionality:

```
createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var url = this.buildURL(type.typeKey);
    var data = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey).serialize(record);
    return this.ajax(url, "POST", { data: data });
},

updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey).serialize(record);
    var id = get(record, 'id'); //todo find pk (not always id)
    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, id), "PUT", { data: data });
},
```